# Is it possible in Google Earth to embed HTTP text/HTML output into a Placemark's balloon description area?

Tags: html, http, kml, google-earth

I'm displaying KML placemark data in Google Earth via a NetworkLink, and would like to keep the size of the KML down by not including the description text in the Placemarks' KML definitions. Instead, I would like to retrieve and embed remote HTML text (via an HTTP request) only when the balloon window is activated.

Is this possible? I know the description format can handle remote images, but is it possible to do this for a block of HTML-formatted text as well? Something like specifying a URL in the Placemark's KML definition that will be retrieved upon the display of the Placemark's balloon window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try putting iframe there:

```
 <iframe src="...."></iframe>
```

i am not sure if google earth allows remote sources to be included via iframe as this could be a possible security problem, though.

Comment: Yeah, <iframe> works -- I had tried it earlier, but on a URL requiring connection through my company's proxy. Putting an internal URL in the iframe worked fine. Apparently, the embedded WebKit browser in GE is not picking up the proxy settings from Internet Options. (The main GE interface does, however, as map data is being downloaded without issues).